# "The data at the root level is invalid" Error when using a Web Serivce

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, web-services

I'm trying to run a method of a Web Service in a desktop .net app but have a problem in phrasing its XML result. when i run the mentioned method compiler throws this error:

> There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network.
>   See inner exception for more details.

the Web service is hosted on Apache server and has written with PHP.
there is a client sample which could run that method successfully. and the result XML is as this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <ServicesList>
  <Service>   
        <token>11838-78</token>    
        <coName>test</coName>    
  </Service>
  </ServicesList>
```

here is part of the details of  inner exception which says: "The data at the root level is invalid"

```
Message=The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   Source=System.Runtime.Serialization
   LineNumber=0
   LinePosition=0
   StackTrace:
        at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
        at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
        at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()
        at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName, XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)
        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   InnerException:
```

I have spending so much time on Google to find out what the problem is from. and just figured out that it maybe the result XML starts with BOM (Byte order mark) which cause the XMLReader to throw exception.

finally here is where i call the method:

```
 mywebservice.wsobjectDLPortTypeClient mys = new mywebservice.wsobjectDLPortTypeClient();
        try
        {
            string res;
       //     mys.Open();              
            res = mys.srvReq(sourcecode, destinationcode, date, time, count);
         catch (Exception e)
        {
           //do something
        }
```

any body know what is that cause this problem and how i can solve it?

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with your example xml, so that suggests there's something before it in the stream. Get your code to dump it to a file and have a look. You are instantiating a new reader each message?

Comment: I didn't manipulate a XMLReader directly. i have just called that method using a wrapper which VS has created it when i tried to added service reference to my project.

Comment: let's edit my post to add my code

Comment: i have inserted the code where calling web service method

Comment: Can you get the raw bytes from a service call? If we can see the first 40-50 bytes of the string it would help.

Comment: Unfortunately  i don't know how to get the raw bytes :(

Comment: Have you tried intercepting the 'data on the wire' with Fiddler (or simalar tool). That might give more insight.